# How to provide NFS access over an ssh tunnel?

Tags: mount, nfs, ssh-tunnel

I have two Raspberries Pi on my home LAN - `rasrho` and `rasnu`. `rasrho` has an ssh port forwarded to it by my router, such that I can ssh to it from outside my LAN.  `rasnu` is running an NFS server. My eventual goal is to allow an external user (who has ssh access to `rasrho`) to be able to mount the NFS server hosted on `rasnu` - but, so far, I cannot even connect over an ssh tunnel *internally*.

The NFS server on `rasnu` is configured such that other machines on my LAN can successfully connect:

```
pi@rasrho:~ $ ls /mnt/NFSDirectory
[null]
pi@rasrho:~ $ sudo mount -t nfs rasnu.local:/media /mnt/NFSDirectory
pi@rasrho:~ $ ls /mnt/NFSDirectory
[listing of the directories from the NFS Server]
```

However, when I set up an ssh tunnel from `rasrho` to `rasnu`, mounting fails (port references from [here](http://biowiki.org/wiki/index.php/Mounting_NFSThrough_SSHTunnel#Open_SSH_tunnel_2_.28from_gateway_to_NFS_server.29)):

```
pi@rasrho:~ $ ssh -fN -L 2049:localhost:2049 pi@rasnu.local
pi@rasrho:~ $ ssh -fN -L 32323:localhost:32323 pi@rasnu.local
pi@rasrho:~ $ ls /mnt/NFSDirectory
[null]
pi@rasrho:~ $ sudo mount -vvv -t nfs4 localhost:/media /mnt/NFSDirectory
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Apr  9 06:36:19 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=::1,clientaddr=::1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=::1,clientaddr=::1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=127.0.0.1,clientaddr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting localhost:/media
```

Despite the server's `/etc/exports` allowing mounting from `127.0.0.1`:

```
pi@rasnu:~ $ cat /etc/exports
/media 192.168.42.0/255.255.255.0(ro,no_subtree_check,insecure)
/media 127.0.0.1(ro,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash)
```

What's wrong in this configuration? And, are there any other hidden "gotchas" that I might encounter in my plan to allow a host on a separate network to mount this NFS server "as if it were local" by executing `ssh -fN -L *:2049:rasnu.local:2049 <external_address_of_rasrho>` (and similar for `32323`)?

(In particular, I have been unable to generate any logs in `/var/log/messages` relating to these permission failures, despite executing `rpcdebug -m nfsd -s all` as per [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-nfs-debug-logging-using-rpcdebug/))

---

EDIT: After reading [this article](http://dag.wiee.rs/blog/tunneling-nfs4-over-ssh), I tried changing my `rasnu`'s `/etc/exports` to read:

```
/mnt/drive *(ro,sync,insecure,hide,no_root_squash,fsid=0,no_subtree_check)
/mnt/drive/media *(ro,sync,insecure,hide,no_root_squash,fsid=1,no_subtree_check)
```

(and ran `sudo exportfs -r` on `rasnu`), then:

```
pi@rasrho:~ $ ls /mnt/NFSDirectory
[null]
pi@rasrho:~ $ ssh -fN -R :3049:rasnu.local:2049 rasrho.local
pi@rasrho:~ $ sudo mount -t nfs -o port=3049 localhost:/media /mnt/NFSDirectory
pi@rasrho:~ $ ls /mnt/NFSDirectory
[...results...]
```

However, I wasn't able to do the equivalent from my Mac (still on the same LAN as these two Raspberries Pi - using `-L` rather than `-R` because I'm trying to forward a local port):

```
me@macbook:~ $ ls /mnt/NFSDirectory
[null]
me@macbook:~ $ ssh -fN -L :3049:rasnu.local:2049 rasrho.local
me@macbook:~ $ sudo mount -t nfs -o port=3049 localhost:/media /mnt/NFSDirectory
mount_nfs: can't mount /media from localhost onto /mnt/NFSDirectory: Connection refused
```

I'll keep experimenting to see if this is just some unusual behaviour from my Mac, and if I can successfully tunnel this NFS mount over the public internet.

Comment: "Permission denied" means your ssh tunnel is working. But your NFS export doesn't allow mounting from the IP is comes from, which should be localhost. My guess would be that ssh is using IPv6 and you should try allowing localhost6 in exports.

Answer (score 1):

Try also creating an ssh tunnel for the mountd port and then mount with the mount option `mountport=$MOUNTD_PORT_ID` as well.

You can find the mountd port by running `sudo netstat -l` on the nfs server and see what mountd is listening on.

So if mountd was listening on 939, create a tunnel to it.

```
ssh -L 3333:127.0.0.1:939 -N $NAS_SERVER
```

Then the mount command would be something like

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o port=3049,mountport=3333 localhost:/media /mnt/NFSDirectory
```